# Asp.net core + Aws Elastic Beanstalk + Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

How can we use bitbucket pipelines to update an asp.net core website on aws elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

i know this is late answer but i did same thing few days ago so here is example how i did it

firstly you have to enable pipeline in bitbucket choose .NET CORE
in bitbucket-pipelines.yml you need yo write something like this:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk
  pipelines:
    branches:
      staging:
        - step:
          name: build publish prepare and zip
          caches:
            - dotnetcore
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install --yes zip
            - export PROJECT_NAME=<your-project-name>
            - dotnet restore
            - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
            - dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime win-x64 --configuration Release 
      
            - zip -j site.zip /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/<your-project-name>/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/win-x64/publish/*  -x aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
            - zip -r -j application.zip site.zip /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/<your-project-name>/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/win-x64/publish/aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json 
          artifacts:
            - application.zip

        - step:
          name: upload to elasticbeanstalk
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.0
            variables:
              APPLICATION_NAME: '<application-name>'
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              #COMMAND: 'upload-only'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: '<environment-name>'
              WAIT: 'true'
```

in settings -> pipelines -> variables you have to set aws keys: access secret and region that will used by $   ($AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

additionally you will have to create s3bucket "-elsticbeanstalk-deployments" (if you dont create it, when the environment will try to upload your zip it will show you error with name of bucket "not found" so just copy the name and create it in s3)